# Powershell on Windows Server 2008R is missing the command Set-AuthConfig

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

I,m wondering why the Powershell command `Set-AuthConfig` is missing on my old Windows Server 2008R, i have **Exchange Server 2010** installed!

Are there any equivalent for that command on a Windows Server 2008R with **Powershell installed** or am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: from the MSDocs site for that cmdlet >>> `Exchange Server 2013, Exchange Server 2016, Exchange Server 2019` <<< //// so, what version of exchange server are you trying to talk to? ///// also, i am surprised that powershell exists on srvr2008.

Comment: Exchange Server 2010 is my old one, the question is also about if there is a replacement for that command `Set-AuthConfig` since i renewed the smtp certificate for my old exchange server as mentioned by microsoft, but i could not finish all steps, because that one command `Set-AuthConfig` is missing.  Any ideas ?

Comment: @ManifestMan You don't need to use that command to replace the certificate. Are you using a trusted 3rd party certificate and not a self-signed one or is it a self-signed cert? I've renewed trusted certs on Exchange 2010 for years with no issue. I still have one coming up in January 2022 here soon for one that is expiring per a Hybrid Exchange 2010 to M365 Exchange Online configuration. Where are you having trouble or what guide are you following exactly? It's Exchange 2010 on Server 2008 R2 as well so it'll work fine without using the PowerShell command you are missing, etc.

Comment: @ManifestMan Also, tell me what format the certificate is in that you are using. Are you using P12, PEM, or what type of cert exactly?

Comment: Okay It's a self signed one @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle

Comment: So you mean i'm good with just renewing my self signed certificate right, i could not find any old documentation on this, that is why i'm asking. If so you can write  down your short answer so i can mark it as solution.

Comment: @ManifestMan - you will likely need to find another way ... there is NO way with standard PoSh or any of the exchange modules for PoSh. _i cannot find any way to do what you want with powershell._ [*blush*]